# Resizing a WebView instance

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm just starting to learn OSX Cocoa app development. I would like to display a website inside a native OSX window. I thought a WebView would be the right way. I would like the webview to always take up 100% of the containing windows' size.

After struggling a bit, I understand how to catch the 'window resize' event, but I have no clue how to resize the web view according to the windows new size.

Here's what I have so far:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *websiteWebview;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (NSSize) windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    WebView *view = [self websiteWebview];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
    return frameSize;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[self window] setDelegate:self];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://conradk.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [[[self websiteWebview] mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

I thought calling `[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)]` would resize the web view as well, but it seems to not be the case.

Any tips / hints please? Is a WebView the right way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your webview isn't resizing at all?  Or it's resizing wrong?

Comment: It's not resizing at all. More precisely, if I make the window larger horizontally, the webview goes to the bottom left of the window (but width and height stay the same). For any other kind of resizing, nothing happens. In all cases, the size of the webview stays the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your `WebView` part of the window's `contentView`.

```
[self.window setContentView:self.websiteWebview];
```

By default, this will let the `webView` auto-resize with the window.  You'll only need to mess with the sizing if you want the webview to do something other than match the size of the window.

Comment: That does not seem to work on my side. Have you tried it? Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: Did you delete (comment out) the stuff in `windowWillResize`?  I haven't tried it on my end... I don't have access to a Mac here.  And I'm not perfectly familiar with developing for OSX, just iOS, but there's lots of overlap...

Comment: Yes, I did. But your answer helped a lot, as it helped me understand things a bit, so I looked at the source! Here's a working solution: `[[self window] setContentView:[self websiteWebview]];`

Comment: Okay, so the correct answer is what I just edited it to (so anyone who sees this in the future will see the right way in an answer rather than just a comment)?

Comment: There is no need for the `autoResizeMask` thing. I guess it's the default for the window's main view.